# Nservicebus Full duplex deployment to dev not working

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, nservicebus

When I run the full duplex sample from Visual Studio everything works without an issue. So I tried to deploy the Myserver as a windows service following the guidelines on nservicebus site. I am running the client as executable i.e clicking on nservice host.exe in the client/bin folder. I am getting errors saying queue cannot be created lack of permissions etc. 
Am I missing something here? 
How do i test the full duplex implementation without using Visual Studio...

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Is this the same machine as the one where you are running the sample from VS, or a different machine?

Comment: I tried both same as well as different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using msmq ensure that the account you are running your service under has access the relevant queues if they already exist.  If they do not exist ensure that the service account has permission to create the queues.